# ncurses new_menu segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, ncurses

I'm having trouble creating a simple file selection in ncurses. The following code fails, valgring saying "conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) from main.cpp:122"

```
  // Create items 
  m_MenuItems = new ITEM * [ m_Files.size() + 1 ];

  int i = 0;
  for ( vector < CFile >::iterator it = m_Files.begin(); it != m_Files.end(); ++it, ++i ) {
    /* m_MenuItems[i] = new_item((*it).pName->c_str(), (*it).pDesc->c_str()); */
    m_MenuItems[i] = new_item("file", "size");
    cout << "[" << i << "]: " << (*it).pName->c_str() << ", " << (*it).pDesc->c_str() << endl;
  } m_MenuItems[++i] = NULL; // Item list has to be null terminated.

  // Create menu
  m_Menu = new_menu( (ITEM **)m_MenuItems ); // ! line 122
  cout << "Success" << endl;
```

The output is exactly this:

```
[0]: main.cpp, 6888
                   [1]: a.out, 106798
                                     [2]: .., 4096
                                                  [3]: listdir.cpp, 701
                                                                       [4]: menu.cpp, 1908
                                                                                          [5]: ., 4096
                                                                                                      Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What could possibly cause the uninitiated variable?

Comment: What does `new_item` return?

Comment: ITEM *new_item(const char *name, const char *description); plus it returns NULL on error.

Comment: What line in the above code is line 122?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan the new_menu line, as noted in the comments.

Comment: Then you should probably check whether it returned NULL before assigning it to `m_MenuItems[i]`

Comment: Verify that you assign NULL to the last array element, and not to the next-after-last one.

Comment: @Named thank you for the suggestion, I have added the check to my code, but in this case none of the return values is null.

Comment: I think @MichaelDorgan has found your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m_MenuItems[++i] = NULL` at the end of your for loop will cause an extra "bad" entry to be added to your list.  You don't need the `++` as `i` will already point 1 past your last entry on exit from the loop.

Also, if `new_item(...)` can return NULL, you should probably check for that and `break` there after assignment into your list as any items following it will be ignored if I understand the code correctly.